# Questions tagged as ExactTarget answered with Salesforce info

Tags: discussion

I know there has been some confusion around the tagging of ExactTarget, etc.  In an effort to relieve some confusion - is there something else I need to be doing aside from ensuring the proper tags?  We have been getting some tagged questions answered with Salesforce related answers that are way off.

Let me know your thoughts on what I can do to improve the overall experiences for everyone.

Answer (score 12):

I think this is mainly due to the knowledge gap of the world of Salesforce and ExactTarget colliding and merging (not a bad thing). People want to help and may sometimes try to do that based on a hunch. As our mutual knowledge grows, these events should decrease.

I think the downvote and comment approach is best and prefered. You can express disagreement and explain why you think or know a certain answer is incorrect. Doing so in full transparency is part of how stackexchange websites work. It can not only educate the person who answered incorrectly, but also everyone else who sees the answer.

Comment: At least in my case, I accidentally stumble across them because I fail to read the tags first. I've yet to actually (incorrectly) answer one, but I think it's just going to take some getting used to; us old dogs are still trying to wrap our heads around the new visitors.

Answer (score 7):

It might be useful to remind those of us who know nothing about exacttarget about the ignored tags feature. I have it set to grey out all exacttarget questions so that I don't mistakenly post force.com answers to them if I forget to check the tags.

Comment: I think you just did that!